# AngularJS UI-Router : Get the absolute URL of the state with the parameters

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I wanted to be able to change the address' URL without changing the state, as to prevent rerendering. From my search, `ui-router` currently does not provide this, but `$location.path` from anuglar does.

So, naturally, I wanted to use `$state.get(stateName)` to get to the state's URL, so that I don't manually type the URL.

I have two problems:

1. `$state.get(stateName)` returns the relative path only. How can I get the absolute path?
2. It also returns the state's definition, with the parameters undefined. How can I get the URL with the parameter in place?

For instance, if I have a state called `user.home.view` with `user.home`, I have my states defined as

```
'user': {
     abstract: true,
     url: '^/users/'
},
'user.home': {
     url: ''
},
'user.home.view': {
     url: ':id/'
}
```

So right now, `$state.get(user.home.view).url` returns `:id/`. How can I get the full URL (i.e., `/users/5/`)?

Answer (score 127, accepted):

You should use `$state.href()`.

1. To get the absolute URL you can then use:

   `$state.href('user.home.view', {}, {absolute: true});`
2. To get the URL with the parameters in place you need to add them as the second argument

Comment: Can you reverse this? Get the state from an href?

Comment: I would suggest to have a look at ui.router.util
http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.util.type:UrlMatcher

Answer (score 101):

What about :

```
$state.href($state.current.name, $state.params, {absolute: true})
```

Comment: the most useful and complete answer!

Answer (score 2):

For getting the absolute URL without parameters, I'm finding I need to pass `inherit: false`, eg:

```
$state.href('home', {}, {absolute: true, inherit: false})
```

Without `inherit: false` I was getting any/all params that may be present.