# Open angularjs state in new window

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using `angular-router` for page navigation. I need to open the new state in a new window. Is it possible? In my `ng-click` function I am using following state method.

```
$state.go('root.newpage', {uIds :Id});
```

I tried with the following code but I get `404 error`

```
$window.open($state.go('root.newpage', {uIds :Id}), '_blank');
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29075249

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS UI-Router : Get the absolute URL of the state with the parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24502065/angularjs-ui-router-get-the-absolute-url-of-the-state-with-the-parameters)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angularjs $state open link in new tab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23516289/angularjs-state-open-link-in-new-tab)

Comment: You may find the answer here [Open angularjs state in new window](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51565518/1959948)