# $state.href with absolute: true doesn't return the right url

Tags: angularjs

I'm using Angular and UI router. I'm trying to get a link shown on the page that the user can copy and share. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24502065/angularjs-ui-router-get-the-absolute-url-of-the-state-with-the-parameters) has shown me that `$state.href` is the function I'm looking for, however it isn't generating the correct link.

An important detail here is that the root of my application is not the root of the domain. In this case, the domain is `localhost`, but the root of the angular app is in `localhost/dev/app/`.

Here's the command I'm using inside my controller.

```
$scope.url = $state.href('survey', { survey: "asd" }, {absolute: true});
```

In my app.js, the following route is declared:

```
.state('survey', {
    url: "/:survey/survey?ao",
    templateUrl: "views/survey/survey.html",
    controller: "surveyController",
    },
    data: { 
        requireLogin: false,
        requireAdmin: false
    }})
```

This should return `http://localhost/dev/app/#/asd/survey`, instead it returns `http://localhost/#/asd/survey`.

(The remarkable thing is that `ui-sref="survey({survey: "asd"})` does translate to the correct link.)

Is there a way I can fix this so I get the full url?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding a `base` tag to my app page solved this issue for me.  It defines the base URL for the page with the router references.  For legacy support reasons, I'm on version 0.2.15 of Angular UI Router.  I don't know if this is still necessary for more current versions.

```
<base href="http://localhost/dev/app/" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.state('survey', {
  url: "/:survey/survey?ao",
  templateUrl: "views/survey/survey.html",
  controller: "surveyController",
  data: { 
    requireLogin: false,
    requireAdmin: false
  }
})
```

You had an extra '},' in after controller, maybe that is messing things up? Also if you're passing parameters you might want to include that as a params line:

```
params: {
  survey: null
}
```

Also if you want the url http://localhost/dev/app/#/asd/survey your url should be:

```
url: "dev/app/:survey/asd/survey"
```